How to put a router with DHCP between my computers and the modem while keeping the 192.168.0.x addresses?
My internet provider has occasional issues and the modem that is a DHCP server for my computers leaves me without a local network until their issue is resolved. So I figured if I put a router (with a DHCP server and disable the DHCP server on the modem) between the computers and the modem I can keep my LAN on while the modem is off. I don't want to change the IP addresses of the computers that are now 192.168.0.x so how do I do that correctly?

John, I don't want the DHCP server of the modem because the LAN goes down every time the internet provider has issues - this is why I want to add the router, so that the router keeps my LAN up. If I just connect the computers to the router and I give it the same IP as the modem - it will work, but what happens when I connect the modem to the router and the modem has the same IP as the router?

A router cannot function properly when its WAN IP and LAN IPs are in the same range. unless you can change the ISPs dhcp server to use a different IP address for the WAN network, you will not be able to make this change without changing the LAN IP addresses. one of the two has to change.  I also do recommend against using 192.168.0.0/24 (and other common device default IP addresses) because they can make creating VPN connection between sites very difficult, but that is up to you.
